# Static objects and singletons

Tags: c++, function, boost, singleton, call

I'm using boost singletons (from serialization).

For example, there are some classes which inherit `boost::serialization::singleton`. Each of them has such define near it's definition (in h-file):

```
#define appManager ApplicationManager::get_const_instance()
class ApplicationManager: public boost::serialization::singleton<ApplicationManager> { ... };
```

And I have to call some method from that class each update (nearly 17 ms), for example, 200 times. So the code is like:

```
for (int i=0; i < 200; ++i)
   appManager.get_some_var();
```

I looked with `gprof` at function call stack and saw that `boost::get_const_instance` calls each time. Maybe, in release-mode compiler will optimize this?

My idea is to make some global variable like:

```
ApplicationManager &handle = ApplicationManager::get_const_instance();
```

And use `handle`, so it wouldn't call `get_const_instnace` each time. Is that right?

Comment: The easiest solution would be to just not use a Singleton at all.

Comment: @deadmg I knew someone would post this :) Please, no words about using singletons, they will be in any case.

Comment: Someone always posts it because it's true.

Comment: Drop the #define and use an inline function, Please Oh Please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using the [Singleton anti-pattern](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/337), just a global variable and be done with it.  It's more honest.

The main benefit of Singleton is when you want lazy initialization, or more fine grained control over initialization order than a global variable would allow you.  It doesn't look like either of these things are a concern for you, so just use a global.

Personally, I think designs with global variables or Singletons are almost certainly broken.  But to each h(is/er) own.

If you are bent on using a Singleton, the performance concern you raise is interesting, but likely not an issue as the function call overhead is probably less than 100ns.  As was pointed out, you should profile.  If it really concerns you a whole lot, store a local reference to the Singleton before the loop:

```
ApplicationManager &myAppManager = appManager;
for (int i=0; i < 200; ++i)
   myAppManager.get_some_var();
```

BTW, using that `#define` in that way is a serious mistake.  Almost all cases where you use the preprocessor for anything other than conditional compilation based on compile-time flags is probably a poor use.  Boost does make extensive use of the pre-processor, but mostly to get around C++ limitations.  Do not emulate it.

Lastly, that function is probably doing something important.  One of the jobs of a `get_instance` method for Singletons is to avoid having multiple threads initialize the same Singleton at the same time.  With global variables this shouldn't be an issue because they should be initialized before you've started any threads.

Comment: I can't agree more. I just coded a singleton to patch a broken design.

Answer (score 2):

Is it really a problem? I mean, does your application really suffers for this behaviour?

I would despise such a solution because, in all effects, you are countering one of the benefits of the Singleton pattern, namely to avoid global variables. If you want to use a global variable, then don't use Singleton at all, right?

Comment: Yes, I'm writing 3d-application (game). And that is just an example. But the speed is really-really important thing.

Comment: So, maybe writing my own singleton class with direct access to instance would be better?

Comment: You should profile it. Anyway, if you code your own singleton class with *inline* accessor, you *should* obtain better performance.

Comment: @Ockonal - The function call overhead is probably on the order of a 100 nanoseconds or so.  I doubt it's an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is certainly a possible solution.  I'm not entirely sure what boost is doing with its singleton behind the scenes; you can look that up yourself in the code.

The singleton pattern is just like creating a global object and accessing the global object, in most respects.  There are some differences:

1) The singleton object instance is not created until it is first accessed, whereas the global object is created at program startup.
2) Because the singleton object is not created until it is first accessed, it is actually created when the program is running.  Thus the singleton instance has access to other fully constructed objects in the program when the constructor is actually running.
3) Because you access the singleton through the getInstance() method (boost's get_const_instance method) there is a little bit of overhead for executing that method call.

So if you're not concerned about when the singleton is actually created, and can live with it being created at program startup, you could just go with a global variable and access that.  If you really need the singleton created after the program starts up, then you need the singleton.  In that case, you can grab and hold onto a reference to the object returned by get_const_instance() and use that reference.

Something that bit me in the past though you should be aware of.  You're actually getting a reference to the object that is owned by the singleton.  You don't own that object.

1) Do not write code that would cause the destructor to execute (say, using a shared pointer on the returned reference), or write any other code that could cause the object to end up in a bad state.

2) In a multi-threaded app, take care to correctly lock fields in the object if the object may be used by more than one thread.

3) In a multi-threaded app, make sure that all threads that hold onto references to the object terminate before the program is unloaded.  I've seen a case where the singleton's code resides in one DLL library; a thread that holds the reference lives in another DLL library.  When the program ends, the thread was still active.  The DLL holding the singleton's code was unloaded first; the thread that was still alive tried to do something to the singleton's object and caused a crash.

Answer (score 1):

Singletons have their advantages in situations where you want to control the level of access to something at process or application scope beyond what a global variable could achieve in a more elegant way.

However most singleton objects provided in a library will be designed to ensure some level of thread safety and most likely access to the instance is being locked via a mutex or other critical section of some kind which can affect performance.

In the case of a game or 3d application where performance is key you may want to consider making your own lightweight singleton if thread safety is not a concern and gain some performance.